# can not start firefoxdriver block by error WebDriverException

Tags: selenium, webdriver

When I try to use

```
WebDriver driver = new  FirefoxDriver();
```

get following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Build info: version: 2.14.0, revision: unknown, time: 2011-11-29 13:13:16
System info: os.name: Windows XP, os.arch: x86, os.version: 5.1, java.version: 1.6.0_29
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:115)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:147)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:75)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:126)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:77)
```

and similar issue happen for

```
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
```

related error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
    at org.apache.http.params.AbstractHttpParams.<init>(AbstractHttpParams.java:5)
    at org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams.<init>(BasicHttpParams.java:6)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.<init>(HttpCommandExecutor.java:203)
    at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.setup(InternetExplorerDriver.java:84)
    at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.<init>(InternetExplorerDriver.java:48)
```

Anybody know why?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is, this is related to the version of webdriver you are using. Try with the latest version, if you have not done so already.

Answer (score 0):

I used the python bindings for selenium but got a similar error. It turns out that you many need to run your code as the root user. Source: http://osdir.com/ml/selenium-users/2011-07/msg01149.html

Edit:
Apparently, it has to do with the http_proxy environment variable. "This issue can be fixed by setting the no_proxy environment variable for localhost."
http://osdir.com/ml/selenium-users/2011-07/msg01169.html

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the version incompatibility between Selenium Firefox webdriver and Firefox binary. So basically your Selenium doesn't support the newest Firefox binary.

Therefore you need to upgrade and use your more recent Selenium jar files.

If you're using Maven, to check which version you're using, run:

```
mvn dependency:tree | grep selenium-firefox-driver
```

So basically if you're using Selenium `2.53.x`, you should upgrade it to [`3.5.x`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java) (e.g. 3.5.2).

See:

- [Selenium webdriver not working with Firefox 26+](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20897368/55075)
- [Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 at GitHub](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/900)