# Selenium webdriver fails to start with Firefox 26+

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I was using selenium 2.35 with previous versions of firefox before it got updated to version firefox 26.0.My tests were running fine previously but now I end up getting the following error.

```
 org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
*** LOG addons.manager: Application has been upgraded
*** LOG addons.xpi: startup
*** LOG addons.xpi: Skipping unavailable install location app-system-local
*** LOG addons.xpi: Skipping unavailable install location app-system-share
*** LOG addons.xpi: Ignoring file entry whose name is not a valid add-on ID: C:\Users\VISHAL~1.SIN\AppData\Local\Temp\anonymous4627406201097696285webdriver-profile\extensions\webdriver-staging
*** LOG addons.xpi: checkForChanges
*** LOG addons.xpi-utils: Opening XPI database C:\Users\VISHAL~1.SIN\AppData\Local\Temp\anonymous4627406201097696285webdriver-profile\extensions.json
*** LOG addons.xpi: New add-on fxdriver@googlecode.com installed in app-profile
*** Blocklist::_loadBlocklistFromFile: blocklist is disabled
*** LOG addons.xpi-utils: Make addon app-profile:fxdriver@googlecode.com visible
*** LOG DeferredSave/extensions.json: Save changes
*** LOG DeferredSave/extensions.json: Save changes
*** LOG addons.xpi: New add-on {9F17B1A2-7317-49ef-BCB7-7BB47BDE10F8} installed in winreg-app-user
*** LOG addons.xpi-utils: Make addon winreg-app-user:{9F17B1A2-7317-49ef-BCB7-7BB47BDE10F8} visible
*** LOG DeferredSave/extensions.json: Save changes
*** LOG DeferredSave/extensions.json: Save changes
*** LOG addons.xpi: New add-on {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} installed in app-global
*** LOG addons.xpi-utils: Make addon app-global:{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} visible
*** LOG DeferredSave/extensions.json: Save changes
*** LOG DeferredSave/extensions.json: Save changes
*** LOG addons.xpi: New add-on {9F17B1A2-7317-49ef-BCB7-7BB47BDE10F8} installed in winreg-app-global
*** LOG DeferredSave/extensions.json: Save changes
*** LOG addons.xpi: New add-on mgsusageagent@managesoft.com installed in winreg-app-global
*** LOG addons.xpi-utils: Make addon winreg-app-global:mgsusageagent@managesoft.com visible
*** LOG DeferredSave/extensions.json: Save changes
*** LOG DeferredSave/extensions.json: Save changes
*** LOG addons.xpi: Updating database with changes to installed add-ons
*** LOG addons.xpi-utils: Updating add-on states
*** LOG addons.xpi-utils: Writing add-ons list
*** LOG DeferredSave/extensions.json: Starting timer
*** LOG DeferredSave/extensions.json: Starting write
*** LOG DeferredSave/extensions.json: Write succeeded
*** LOG addons.xpi-utils: XPI Database saved, setting schema version preference to 15
*** LOG addons.manager: shutdown
*** LOG addons.xpi: shutdown
*** LOG addons.xpi-utils: shutdown
*** LOG addons.xpi: Notifying XPI shutdown observers
*** LOG addons.manager: Async provider shutdown done
*** LOG addons.xpi: startup
*** LOG addons.xpi: Skipping unavailable install location app-system-local
*** LOG addons.xpi: Skipping unavailable install location app-system-share
*** LOG addons.xpi: Ignoring file entry whose name is not a valid add-on ID: C:\Users\VISHAL~1.SIN\AppData\Local\Temp\anonymous4627406201097696285webdriver-profile\extensions\webdriver-staging
*** LOG addons.xpi: checkForChanges
*** LOG addons.xpi: No changes found
JavaScript error: chrome://browser/content/urlbarBindings.xml, line 654: aUrl is undefined
```

I tried to downgrade the version of firefox but am unable to get any previous versions from the mozilla site.

I also tried all the selenium versions 2.36,2.37,2.38,2.39 but none of them seems to be compatible with firefox 26.0. There are errors in the code once I try to replace the selenium 2.35 with 2.36 to 2.39. These errors disappear when I replace again with 2.35.

Can anybody help me with the compatible versions of Selenium and Firefox?

Comment: You may look at here for older versions of firefox :http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/

Comment: @Suresh Atta  The mentioned link is not opening..

Comment: http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/

Comment: Add http before.Might firewall blocking

Comment: Downgrade your firefox and upgrade your webdriver this will fix your issue.

Comment: You can use this link to download older versions of firefox : http://www.filehippo.com/download_firefox/history/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use any version of selenium from 2.XX but there is only limitation that we can use only firefox25 or firefox 14.01 to 17.XX

Comment: thanks for that info..can you also let me know from where I can downoad the above mentioned firefox set up.

Comment: The one given by Suresh Atta does not seem to open.

Comment: great thanks! unfortunately firefox 25.00 didn't work for me; 17 worked for me perfectly!

Answer (score 5):

The reason for the:

> Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055

error is that the version of Selenium Server does not know how to work with the newer version of Firefox. You need to download a newer version of the Selenium Server that supports the newer version of Firefox.

See: [Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 at GitHub](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/900).

Answer (score 2):

Firefox 26 with works with selenium 2.39

```
<seleniumVersion>2.39.0</seleniumVersion>
```

Answer (score 0):

use firefox 25 , it works fine on FF25

Comment: can you let me know the combination? I mean Firefox 25 with selenium 2.39? or anyother combination?

Comment: ff 25 & selenium 2.25